# How to add values to lookup fields of objects extended in other packages?

Tags: apex, soql

I have added an object in my 'Car' package let's say 'Car_Segment__c'. I have a lookup field 'Car_Model__c' for this object. There is another package 'Tyres' which has an object 'Tyre_Quality__c'. In the 'Tyres' package I need to extend the 'Car_Segment__c' object and add a lookup to the field 'Tyre_Quality__c'. For this purpose I added an object to 'Tyres' package named 'car__Car_Segment__c' and then a lookup field named 'Quality__c'. The 'referenceTo' tag inside this xml of 'Quality__c' looks like -

```
<referenceTo>Tyre_Quality__c</referenceTo>
```

If I want to instantiate an object of 'Car_Segment__c' and assign a value to field  then I can simply do the below and the field value gets inserted without any issues -

```
Car_Segment__c carSegment = new Car_Segment__c();
carSegment.Car_Model__c = '0034R00003bVDo1QAG';
insert carSegment;
```

Now in my apex code I have a requirement in a class CarSegment.cls to add a value to the lookup 'Tyre_Quality__C'.
However I am not sure how do I instantiate and assign the values of the extended object lying in package 'Tyres'. Is something like below possible -

```
car__Car_Segment__c extendedCarSegment = new car__Car_Segment__c();
  extendedCarSegment.Tyres__Tyre_Quality__c = '0034R00003bVDo1BCG';
  insert extendedCarSegment;
```

or

```
Sobject.put('Tyres__Tyre_Quality__c', '0034R00003bVDo1BCG');
  insert Sobject;
```

What's the correct way to do this ? Also is there a concrete way to even check from my package that the field I am refering to in the other package exists or not ?

Answer (score 0):

It's critical to be clear about (a) what the packages involved are; (b) their mutual relationship; and (c) their namespaces, if any.

You have a package called Cars with namespace `car`. You also have a package Tyres with namespace `Tyres`. What's not clear is the relationship between them:

> There is another package 'Tyres' which has an object 'Tyre_Quality__c'. In the 'Tyres' package I need to extend the 'Car_Segment__c' object

This means that "Tyres" has a dependency on "Cars".

> Now in my apex code I have a requirement in a class CarSegment.cls to add a value to the lookup 'Tyre_Quality__C'.

`CarSegment.cls` *seems* to be part of "Cars", which would be a problem because you would then have a circular dependency between "Cars" and "Tyres". If it's not, and this class exists in some third package or is outside both packages, you would do this version:

```
car__Car_Segment__c extendedCarSegment = new car__Car_Segment__c();
extendedCarSegment.Tyres__Tyre_Quality__c = '0034R00003bVDo1BCG';
insert extendedCarSegment;
```

Note that you use the namespaces of both packages to reference the schema entities they contain, in code that exists outside the package. (Also, you shouldn't ever hard-code an Id, but since that's a Contact Id I'm assuming it's for illustration).